# Shell command from Python "env: node: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, node.js, macos, shell

I got a Node.js CLI program called [meyda](https://meyda.js.org/guides/offline-cli) installed (Mac OS 10.14) using:

```
sudo npm install --global meyda
```

From the Terminal I can call the program and it works as expected; like:

```
meyda --bs=256 --o=apagodis2.csv DczN6842.wav rms
```

Now, I want to call it from inside a python script (using Spyder) at the same location and tried this – but getting error:

```
import os
os.system ('/usr/local/bin/meyda --bs=256 --o=apagodis4.csv samples_training/DczN6842.wav rms')
>>> env: node: No such file or directory
```

I can issue more "traditional" shell commands like this from the same Python script and it works:

```
os.system ('cp samples_training/DczN6842.wav copy.wav')
```

Also tried `subprocess call` with same result. I confirmed the executable is at `/usr/local/bin/`

To make sure I also removed all file arguments calling the program using only the help flag but same, error.

```
os.system ('/usr/local/bin/meyda -h')
>>> env: node: No such file or directory
```

Why is the command not found from inside Python but sucessfully in the macOS Terminal?

Comment: Where's node installed on your machine? Try adding that before the `meyda` call

Comment: `which node`says `/usr/local/bin/node`
So it's the same place. So it should be just like you propose using `/usr/local/bin/meyda` like I do.

Comment: Is the `/usr/local/bin/meyda` file a script starting with something like `#!/usr/bin/env node`? If so, the problem is that it requires that the location of `node` (i.e. `/usr/local/bin`) be in your `PATH`. Try `os.system('echo "$PATH"')` and see what it prints.

Comment: Indeed, from Python `os.system('echo "$PATH"')` does not show `/usr/local/bin` so what do I do now? Another thing: in Terminal `echo "$PATH"` will show `/usr/local/bin`, how come it's not the same paths shown?

Comment: I just noticed the meyda is a soft-link (right word?) to: `meyda -> ../lib/node_modules/meyda/bin/cli.js`, don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Oortone try `os.system ('/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/meyda -h')`

Comment: Great, that was the solution. Now it works. And now I get what you meant in your previous post.